# Si vas a responder tu pregunta, hazlo antes de publicar la pregunta

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido, respuesta-propia, artículo

Si vas a publicar una pregunta y a responderla tu mismo hay una forma correcta de hacerlo.

## Responderla antes de publicar la pregunta.

Marca la casilla apropiada y escribe la respuesta junto con la pregunta. Escribir la pregunta y publicarla. Dedicar unos minutos a la respuesta y publicarla después es una falta de cortesía. Habrá gente que dedicará inútilmente su tiempo a escribir una respuesta a tu pregunta que no es necesaria. No les/nos hagas perder el tiempo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muy importante en las traducciones: **incluir la atribución**. Enlace a la pregunta/respuesta que ha sido traducida. Opcional, brindar un enlace al perfil de quienes redactaron la pregunta/respuesta original.

No es solo una cuestión de cortesía. Es un requisito de la licencia (ver al final de todas las páginas de stackoverflow): contribuciones de los usuarios bajo licencia [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) con [atribución requerida](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)
También hay que hacerlo con cualquier cosa que copies. Ahí pueden haber mil casos y licencias pero lo cortés es siempre atribuir.

El no hacerlo así, el publicar primero la pregunta y luego, al poco tiempo, la respuesta es una anti-contribución. Es disruptivo. Reduce la calidad del sitio pues se dificulta el trabajo de contribución cooperativa. Entiendo que habrá muchos casos en que no se actúa de mala fe y es cuestión de desconocimiento. Eduquémolos con un enlace a este mensaje. Al que reincide -1, está haciendo contribuciones de baja calidad.

Si has escrito la pregunta y te tienes que ir o no te da tiempo a escribir la respuesta pues no la publiques. Haz un copiar-pegar y guárdala en un archivo. O utiliza el borrador de StackOverflow (Stack Exchange guarda automáticamente las preguntas y respuestas a medio redactar como borradores). Otro día podrás acabar. O publícala si quieres, pero no escribas la respuesta, deja que lo haga otro. Si en un par de días nadie da una respuesta que te satisfaga escribe entonces tu respuesta.

Comment: No ando acompañando mucho, pero veo que el tema parece caliente... ¿está ocurriendo una [Gold Rush](https://boredanddangerousblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/gold-rush.jpg) en el site?

Comment: También se puede mencionar que Stack Exchange guarda automáticamente las preguntas y respuestas como borradores o bien, que las preguntas y respuestas eliminadas pueden ser editadas y recuperadas.

Comment: @Rubén, ya había mencionado el borrador de StackOverflow, pero lo pongo con más detalle como sugieres.

Comment: Mira que llevo tiempo en SOen y nunca había visto esa casilla. Muchísimas gracias por esta aportación. La verdad que siempre me había preguntado cómo la gente podía editar las respuestas tan rápido como para poder responderlas en el mismo minuto en el que realizan la pregunta. Ahora lo entiendo todo.

Comment: Esto no tiene que ver nada con cortesía... es una opción más para contribuir buenas o correctas respuestas (por uno mismo) da igual si tardas en contestarlo o no...

Comment: Hacer perder el tiempo a los demás es una falta de cortesía. Si ya tienes la respuesta a tu pregunta pero no la publicas junto a la pregunta estás aparentando que necesitas una respuesta y habrá quien se dedique a redactar una respuesta; esfuerzo desperdiciado en la mayoría de los casos en que quien pregunta ya tenía la respuesta..

Comment: Si piensas que contestar a una pregunta es perder el tiempo entonces estás equivocado de sitio... quizás puedas mejorar la respuesta del OP o aprender de los fallos o mejorar tus *skills*.... y eso es sin duda ninguna perdida de tiempo....

Comment: Esta pregunta fue reportada como que se basa principalmente en opiniones, ante la duda, decido omitir y no revisarla.

Comment: @ArtEze Realmente la mayoría de preguntas establecidas como "discusión" se basan en opiniones. Sinceramente no sé para que está esa opción en meta.

Comment: una consulta para los que llevan mas tienpo en el sitio. si ya sabes la respuesta,¿para que vas a iniciar la pregunta?¿no seria una forma de "malgastar" recursos?

Comment: @bassily , si ya sabes la respuesta, hacer la pregunta y esperar a que otro te responda es malgastar recursos (hacer perder el tiempo) en SO y en todas partes. Muy distinto es si publicas pregunta y respuesta a la vez; entoces estás compartiendo tu conocimiento. Si tu respuesta es mejorable es posible que aparezcan otras respuestas, lo cual también beneficia al que publicó originalmente. Por cierto, en SO se considera especialmente útil el autoresponder preguntas si reciben tres al menos 3 puntos; eso no es una opinión.