# Preguntas y respuestas del mismo usuario de forma repetida

Tags: discusión, respuesta-propia

Es totalmente válido que un usuario responda su propia pregunta pero veo que en los últimos tiempos algún usuario viene haciendo eso de forma repetida y con escasos minutos entre pregunta y respuesta detallada lo que lleva a suponer que la pregunta ya tenía una respuesta elaborada y se pierde un poco el espíritu de 'SO en español', es decir, que alguien tenga una duda y que otros le respondan generando contenido comunitario.

¿Es este comportamiento reproblable y no atenta al espíritu del sitio?

Ejemplos:

[Sobre unicode y codificación utf-8 en Python 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85920/sobre-unicode-y-codificaci%c3%b3n-utf-8-en-python-3)

[Diferencia entre objetos iterable, iterator y contenedores en Python 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84591/diferencia-entre-objetos-iterable-iterator-y-contenedores-en-python-3)

[Sobrecarga de funciones en C estándar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84185/sobrecarga-de-funciones-en-c-est%c3%a1ndar)

[¿Por qué en C printf() usa %f para float y double y scanf() los diferencia con %f y %lf?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83349/por-qu%c3%a9-en-c-printf-usa-f-para-float-y-double-y-scanf-los-diferencia-con)

...

Enlace relevante:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Se podria considerar reprobable **si en el sitio al momento de aceptar su propia respuesta a su propia pregunta ganase reputacion, como si fuere una pregunta normal**, mas no se gana reputacion, incluso, uno debe esperar **2 dias** para poder aceptar su propia respuesta, esta es una muy buena manera de contribuir al sitio, hay muchos que tienen problemas en sus programas y pueden contribuir con una solucion publicando tanto pregunta como respuesta.

Comment: Relacionado: [Si vas a responder tu pregunta, hazlo antes de publicar la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/182/65)

Comment: Parece claro que no se viola el espíritu comunitario del sitio y mi duda queda resuelta. Muchas gracias por aportar a la conversación. Dejo aprobada la respuesta de @luiggi-mendoza para que quede registro.

Comment: Recuerdo que este tema fue controversial en los inicios del sitio, yo siempre estuve de acuerdo con esto. Finalmente, como menciona Luiggi, la comunidad es la que decide qué contenido permanece.

Comment: Cuando algunos usuarios o yo hemos realizado esto **marcamos la pregunta/respuesta como wiki de comunidad**...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

La acción de publicar una pregunta con su respuesta es válida. El sitio te permite redactar tanto la pregunta como la respuesta y publicarlos en un solo instante. Esto explica que la respuesta ha sido publicada "con escasos minutos" desde que se publicó la pregunta.

Sin embargo, una vez publicada la pregunta, es una pregunta **del sitio**. Esto significa que podemos votar a favor o en contra, y si la pregunta no tiene los estándares de calidad del sitio puede ser votada a cierre por ser demasiado amplia, no está claro lo que se pregunta y demás. Similar con las respuestas: si ayudan y tienen la calidad esperada del sitio, entonces votemos a favor, si son respuestas que confunden o que no explican del todo, se puede votar en contra.

Comment: Gracias. Esto aclara bastante la forma de proceder y tiene sentido.

Comment: Es un tecnicismo. Pero la pregunta no es del sitio, no es propiedad del sitio. El sitio está licenciado para usar la pregunta bajo licencia CC-BY-SA 3.0. Lo cual incluye republicarla con las modificaciones que se desee o dejar de publicarla.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos ajá, lo que digas...

Answer (score 3):

Desde mi punto de vista ese tipo de Q&A las veo más apropiadas para un blog personal sobre programación que para 'SO en español'.

Parece claro que el usuario ya viene con una respuesta creada antes de formular la pregunta y que se desvirtúa un poco el espíritu del sitio.

Dejo el debate aquí para que otros opinen.