# Borrador de pregunta

Tags: característica-nueva, preguntas

Mi pregunta es si se pueden crear borradores de preguntas, me vendrían realmente bien crear preguntas privadas de forma rápida para luego desarrollarlas cuando tenga más tiempo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actualización: La caractarística ya existe oficialmente, de acuerdo a [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/289691) sólo se guarda un borrador de pregunta y una respuesta en cada sitio la red SE y estos se guardan por siete días.

---

En la interfaz web de escritorio si empezamos a redactar una pregunta o respuesta y cerramos el navegador o incluso te cambiamos de navegador/equipo, al ir a la página correspondiente ya sea de nueva pregunta o la pregunta existente, se mostrará lo que hayamos redactado

En el caso de las preguntas sólo se guarda un borrador.

En el caso de las repuestas me parece que se guarda un borrador por cada pregunta.

Te sugiero hacer la prueba, quizás antes de cerrar el navegador copia y guarda el contenido en otra parte, por si acaso.

Relacionado

- [Si vas a responder tu pregunta, hazlo antes de publicar la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/182/65)